# Cómo asignar el valor de un campo en otra tabla con disparador de insert? MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Este es mi código:

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER encendido AFTER UPDATE ON dispositivo 
FOR EACH ROW INSERT actividad 
VALUES ('','',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'', 1);
```

Los campos de la tabla actividad son:

```
CodigoActividad (auto incremento)
```

CodigoDispositivo (este es el que quiero de la tabla dispositivo cuando ese registro de actualice y estaba haciendo algo como: dispositivo.CodigoDispositivo)

```
FechaEncendido

FechaApagado

Estado
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La fila que ha sido actualizada se referencia con la palabra NEW.
Tu código quedaría mas o menos así

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER encendido AFTER UPDATE ON dispositivo 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT into actividad VALUES ('', NEW.CodigoDispositivo , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , '' , 1);
```

Comment: Gracias FederHico. Funcionó a la perfección